# referencing function iterations for dynamically created buttons tkinter

Tags: function, tkinter, dynamically-generated

I have created buttons dynamically and set them to call script function so when `Test 1` is clicked `script_1` is executed, likewise `Test 2` for `script_2` and so on...
but when `Test 1` or `Test 2` is clicked `script_0` is executed. It appears `val = i.get()` always returns the value 0 each time. Is there a way to get the current `i value`?

function

```
def script():
    if running:
        i = IntVar()
        val = i.get()
        subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script_' + str(val) + '.py'])
    root.update()
```

Button

```
for i in range(3):
    button.append(tk.Button(root, text="Test " + str(i + 1), font=(None, 16), command=lambda i=i: script()))
    button[-1].grid(column=0, row=i + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you initialize `i` the line before, and IntVar always initializes to 0. You need to pass `i` as an argument to your script:

```
from Tkinter import Button, IntVar, Tk
import subprocess
def script(i):
    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script_' + str(i) + '.py'])
    root.update()

root = Tk()
button = []   
for i in range(3):
    button.append(Button(root, text="Test " + str(i + 1), font=(None, 16), command=lambda i=i: script(i)))
    button[-1].grid(column=0, row=i + 1)

root.mainloop()
```

This correctly popens script_0.py,1,2 respectively for me. Consider wrapping root in a class as good practice (some like to inherit Tk), and making the buttons a part of `__init__`.