# python 3 table of records and dynamic buttons

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter

I am currently working on developing something similar to the following GUI in python using tkinter:

[image]

I managed to construct and build everything. However, any idea of how to create the table of people waiting in the queue as highlighted above?

I already have the data in a dictionary and want to build my table according to the data in the dictionary.

I want to populate a table like view and have a two buttons to either accept or decline the entry.

I created a for loop that makes these buttons as follow:

```
        for i in range(0,x)
            btn_reject = tk.Button(frame,text="")
            btn_reject.grid(row=i, column=4)
            btn_accept = tk.Button(frame,text="")
            btn_accept.grid(row=i, column=5)
```

Now, how do I know which one of them was pressed since I created them dynamically using this for loop?

I very much appreciate your support.

Comment: This question is unclear and a bit broad. It sounds like you're asking us to give you a complete solution. You ask how to create a table of people waiting in the queue, have you tried simply using a loop?

Comment: Hi Bryan,
Sorry if I was not clear on my question. I just want to know what is the way to create the colored buttons at the right side of the record and how to I know which one was pressed since they are going to be create dynamically.

Comment: I created a loop that produced the records. However, I am not sure of how to create the buttons and how to track which one was pressed. I want to create different actions based on which one was pressed.

Comment: Please see my edit to the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do what is in the following question:

[referencing function iterations for dynamically created buttons tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749969/referencing-function-iterations-for-dynamically-created-buttons-tkinter)

It does what you are looking for.